# Create single binary from express + react app with zeit pkg?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm, zeit-pkg

How do I package an express + react folderstructure into a single binary with zeit?
I can run each of them like this:
node server.js 
npm run start client

I can start both like this:
scripts element in package.json:
  "myapp": "concurrently --kill-others \"node server\" \"npm run --prefix client start\"",

then - npm run myapp in the same folder as package.json.

What I would like to achieve is to apply zeit/pkg somehow so that I have a single binary that I can run that starts both servers in the same way as npm run myapp.

Anyone who knows how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think zeit/pkg accepts multiple entry points based on their [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg#usage)

> The entrypoint of your project is a mandatory CLI argument. It may be:
>
> ```
> Path to entry file. Suppose it is /path/app.js, then packaged app will work the same way as node /path/app.js
> Path to package.json. Pkg will follow bin property of the specified package.json and use it as entry file.
> Path to directory. Pkg will look for package.json in the specified directory. See above.
> ```

Maybe the better route would be to do some server-side rendering via their Next.js framework? Then you would only have to package your app via the NodeJS entry point.